# List problems in foreign key relations

Tags: sql, foreign-key-relationship

I have two tables:

```
create table FOO (
    id integer primary key
);
create table BAR (
    id primary key,
    fooId integer -- yeah, this *should* be a foreign key
);
insert into FOO values (10);
insert into FOO values (11); -- no BAR
insert into BAR values (20, 10); -- OK
insert into BAR values (21, 3); -- No FOO
insert into BAR values (22, 10); -- duplicates are OK
```

For some reason, they don't have a FK relation even though they should. When I create the relation, I get an error because some of the relations are broken.

I'm looking for a SQL query which lists the primary keys of both tables that have a broken relation to the other one, i.e. `FOO`s which aren't used in any `BAR`s and `BAR`s which contain illegal `fooId`s. In the example, the query should return:

```
fooId | barId
11      NULL
NULL    21
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a `UNION ALL` with two `NOT IN`'s:

```
select id, null from FOO where id not in (select fooId from bar where fooId is not null)
union all
select null, id from BAR where fooId not in (select id from foo where id is not null)
```

Or, a `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
select distinct f.id, b.id
from foo f
  full outer join bar b on f.id = b.fooid
where f.id is null
   or b.id is null
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `not exists` (or `not in` or `left join` with a `where` clause):

```
select b.*
from bar b
where not exists (select 1 from foo f where f.id = b.fooid);
```

The only *broken* relationships are those where `bar.fooid` does not match a valid `foo.id`.  Having a value in `foo` with no corresponding value in `bar` is not broken.

But to find `foo.id` values that are not used in `bar`, a very similar query can be used:

```
select f.*
from foo f
where not exists (select 1 from bar b where f.id = b.fooid);
```

Comment: When `FOO` is `Customer` and `BAR` is `Address`, then customers without addresses are broken, too :-)

Comment: @AaronDigulla . . . Not in the database sense (as your tables are set up).  You won't get an error for that case when you try to set up a foreign key relationship.

Comment: I'm aware of that. But for the "please clean this up" kind of report, I need both.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `full outer join`.

```
select foo.id as fooid, bar.id as barid
from foo
full join bar on foo.id = bar.fooid
where foo.id is null or bar.id is null
```